# VBA Copy and Paste to new Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The following code basically copies and pastes from Sheet1 to Sheet2 in the same order it was in on Sheet2. I need it to paste the values into the same column on Sheet2 so I can run a sort for all of the values. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to Paste everything to the same column on Sheet2. Thanks.

Sub InfoSharing()

```
Dim lastrowDB As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim array1, array2, i As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastrowDB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

array1 = Array("C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N")
array2 = Array("C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N")

For i = LBound(array1) To UBound(array1)
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = Application.Max(3, .Cells(.Rows.Count, array1(i)).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Range(.Cells(3, array1(i)), .Cells(lastrow, array1(i))).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range(array2(i) & lastrowDB).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub

Comment: Where do you want to paste data? Do you have excact location?

Comment: it can go anywhere i would like for it to be pasted to A1 so all the values in Sheet2 are in column A.

Comment: Well... your code now copies data and pastes in the same column. So I don't really know what is your problem.

Comment: It counts values from Column A, depending on how many values are there it copies data from Sheet1 range(C3:N3) to row (which depends on that first counting) to Sheet2.

Comment: I need all values in range (C3:N3) to be pasted into column A on Sheet2. So like Sheet1(C3:C17) to Sheet2(A1:A15) then Sheet1(D3:D17) to Sheet2(A16:A30) and so on.

Comment: Just to clarify. You want to paste all cells from `Sheet1` range C3:N3 to `Sheet2` range A1:A12. Then you want you start copy `Sheet1` range D3:N3 (one row below) and then copy that values after already pasted in `Sheet2`, column A, so it would be A13:A24. Is it right? I want to be sure. At first I thought you want to transpose data from one sheet to another but then you showed me different ranges (not horizontal but vertical). Anyway both are possible to do.

Comment: Yes. I need to have all of the data in one column but it comes to my group in several columns. So Sheet1(C3:C17) needs to go to Sheet2(A1:A15) then Sheet1(D3:D17) needs to go to Sheet2(A16:A30) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task is easy to do, just look below:

```
Dim i As Byte, y As Byte, x As Integer

For i = 3 To 5 'i is a number of column counts from left to right in Sheet1 to be copied

    For y = 3 To 17 'y is a number of row in Sheet1 to be copied

        x = x + 1 'x is a number of row in Sheet2 to be pasted

        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(y, i).Value

    Next y

Next i
```

I made a nested loop for your coping problem. It goes as many columns as you need (adjust **i** variable), through as many rows you need (adjust **y** variable) and pasting everything to A columns in Sheet2 (one by one, using **a** variable as a row number.

If you need something more, do not hesitate to ask in the comment.

Comment: Good to hear that. Please mark this post as an anwser. This may help others finding solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use copy/paste if you want to flip the values

You can just set the value property of each cell though.
You'd need to keep track of the current row in column A in the destination sheet.
And then cycle through the rows of the column you are processing and set the value property from the value property of the source cell.

Comment: So i wouldnt be able to copy values from Sheet1 column C and paste to Sheet2 column A and then copy values from Sheet1 column D and paste to the end of column A in sheet2?

Comment: If you are pasting columns, yes.  If you are taking rows and pasting into columns, no.

Comment: It is possible if you use transpose.